# Skype off when write in chat and open the call video in the same time

Tags: 12.04, skype

I don't understand why when I open a video call and write in the same time, skype turns off 
and back again for open it.

I tried again and found the same problem: Skype doesn't let me write while I'm in a video call... Please need help I use it for my study. I use Skype for (ubuntu 12.04 multiraich )

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu. It is hard to tell which problems you're facing. Can you explain it a little better? Also, don't forget to check our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: skype doesn't let me chat and run in the same time call video ..when do this just skype off and sing out !!!!

Comment: I edited your question to clarify it a little bit.

Comment: I have a similar problem occuring since a few days. It has worked before. I guess it's a problem on Microsoft's side, because I changed nothing. Did you install Skype via Software Center? If yes try the installer from the Skype website.

Comment: Mine, which is installed from the Ubuntu Software Centre, works fine. Please let us know which version of Skype you have, and whether you are using 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: my system 64 bit and i just chose skype 12.04 multiraich

Answer (score 0):

The version of Skype on the Ubuntu Software Centre is up-to-date and includes plug-ins for 64-bit.

My suggestion is to uninstall the Skype that you downloaded from the website, and install the Ubuntu version. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

This will prompt for your password.

Then install Skype from the standard repositories. In a terminal, enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

I also recommend that you update all your packages with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```